# How to do a rigged character that supports different anatomy types with morphs?

Tags: rigging

I wish to create multiple rigged low poly characters for a game. To cut production time, I want to know how to merge morphs and bones rigging.

My goal :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jn5j2tvjI7A

How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add Shape Keys]

Click the + button twice. Then go into edit mode and start moving vertices. Or go into or sculpt mode and move the vertices until you have a shape you like, repeat this until you're happy. Make sure while editing that only the key you are working on has a value of 1 and all others are 0, otherwise it might mess up your preview.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Comment: you're welcome, can you press accept on the answer, so others know it's solved?